# Null byte injection still in PHP7?

Tags: php, web, web-applications, penetration-testing

I am wondering if Null Byte Injection is still an issue in PHP7?

If null byte injection is exploitable in PHP7, then how can I prevent it?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know if it has been fixed for `include`/`require` yet, but you can prevent it by not blindly accepting userdata. Validate user input properly as can be seen here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.filesystem.nullbytes.php

Answer (score 1):

I am not completly sure whether all related functions have been fixed in PHP 7.

[file_exists has been fixed for sure](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=39863).

In any case you can prevent it by not blindly accepting user data but validating it before-hand:

```
<?php
$file = $_GET['file']; 

// Whitelisting possible values
switch ($file) {
    case 'main':
    case 'foo':
    case 'bar':
        include '/home/wwwrun/include/'.$file.'.php';
        break;
    default:
        include '/home/wwwrun/include/main.php';
}
?>
```

For more info see http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.filesystem.nullbytes.php